# exim4 & mailersend and Problems with Lists, Aliases & Forwarders

Tags: exim4, mailersend

I have an Ubuntu using exim4 with Digital Ocean. As more and more Blacklist block Digital Ocean and other Cloud Providers without care about the individual Server, our emails are more and more blocked.

As I want to keep the Server for receiving emails and as POP3/IMAP3, I setup exim4 to use mailersend as Smarthost using the manualrouter-Driver. As I have multiple Domains, I added several Domains to mailersend and verify them. It works very well and email will be delivered much better.

But then I noticed a Problem:

I use Aliases, Lists and Forwarders. Some of them include external Mailadresses.

Example:

aliaslist@mydomain.com is a List that send mails to me@mydomain.com,friend@gmail.com

So, now when an E-Mail is send from the Outside for example from someone@icloud.com to aliaslist@mydomain.com, the E-Mail is delivered to me@mydomain.com (because it is local router), but not to friend@gmail.com. It is denied, as Mailersend see as Sender someone@icloud.com and icloud.com is not one of my verified Domains.

As I have a lot of Alias, Forwarders and Lists I try to find a way to still use mailersend, but go around this Problem.

Did anyone run into the problem and find a solution?

I did not find a way to tell exim4.conf that Aliases, Forwarders and Lists should be sent via another Router (like dnslookup) and only all others via smarthost as an example.

Is their any way that I did not see to solve the problem?

Frank